# Laravel Validation: Adding secondary check to row, Only rows with account_id of 1 AND deleted_at IS NULL

Tags: php, laravel, validation

This is from Laravel 4.2 Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-required-without

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'
```

In the rule above, only rows with an account_id of 1 would be included in the unique check.

What I am trying to do is:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1,deleted_at,NULL'
```

In the rule above, only rows with an account_id of 1 and deleted_at is NULL would be included in the unique check.

However this does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: i hope you are not using 4.2

Comment: I am no choice in this matter.

Comment: Legacy software exists, but if possible, consider upgrading Laravel to a more supported version. But that's beside the point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if name is unique among non-deleted items with laravel validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374995/check-if-name-is-unique-among-non-deleted-items-with-laravel-validation)

Comment: tried those did work wrong version of Laravel maybe

Comment: you could enable the query log before you run validation then after dump the query log and see how it is generating the query

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the deleted_at out of the validator and using a separate query becuase what should have worked seemed to be a bug in Laravel 4.2 Framework.