# Laravel unique validation with softdeletes data

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to use Laravel Unique validator with the implementation of softdeletes. I've been try many times but it produce an error like this. What should i do? Thanks in advance. Here's my code example.

[image]

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'nama' => 'required',
        'nim' => [
            'required',
            'size:10',
            Rule::unique('students')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('deleted_at', NULL);
            })
        ],
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    Student::create([
        'major_id' => $request->major_id,
        'nama' => $request->nama,
        'slug' => Str::of($request->nama)->slug('-'),
        'nim' => $request->nim,
        'email' => $request->email,
    ]);
    return redirect('/students')->with('status', 'Success');
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if name is unique among non-deleted items with laravel validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374995/check-if-name-is-unique-among-non-deleted-items-with-laravel-validation)

Comment: you can also see: https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/laravel-soft-delete-unique-validations/

Comment: If you wanna use unique fields in your table, you have two variants: fully remove data from the table, or update needed row with new values and set `deleted_at` to NULL

Comment: I've tried to solve my problem like this https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/laravel-soft-delete-unique-validations/ But It didn't work for me, instead of produce an error like this. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '18.N1.0014' for key 'students_nim_unique' (SQL: insert into `students` (`major_id`, `nama`, `slug`, `nim`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, Geovana Clarissa Mulyono, geovana-clarissa-mulyono, 18.N1.0014, geovanaclarissamulyono@gmail.com, 2021-04-13 04:06:19, 2021-04-13 04:06:19))

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting is from a constraint in your database. Nothing you can do in the code can counter that. The database doesnt care for soft delete.

You need to remove the constraint from the database first, then use your solution or the one from this post [check-if-name-is-unique-among-non-deleted-items-with-laravel-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374995/check-if-name-is-unique-among-non-deleted-items-with-laravel-validation)

To remove the constraint, run this query

```
ALTER TABLE students DROP CONSTRAINT students_nim_unique;
```

The best practice would be to create a new migration running this query. Carefull for the `down()` method, you will not be able to put back the constraint if there are dupplicate nim in the table (soft deleted or not)

Comment: An alternative is to specify a unique constraint for the pair of columns including nim and deleted_at

Comment: @apokryfos That can work, prevents having two vim with null as deleted_at value.

Comment: @apokryfos great solution !!! thanks...